# Prove that a group of order 42 must have a subgroup of order 6

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that a group of order 42 must have a subgroup of order 6.

Firstly, I use Sylow's theorem to show there must exist a subgroup of order **7**. What about 6?

Comment: There can't be 14 Sylow 3 subgroups, so there are 7 or there is 1. 7 means the normalizer has order 6, and you're done. 1 means the Sylow 3 subgroup is normal, and you can take its product with a Sylow 2 subgroup.

Comment: @SteveD I think that comment would be appropriate as an answer. Perhaps you would consider adding it?

Answer (score 3):

The number of Sylow 3-subgroups:

1. is congruent to $1\pmod{3}$
2. divides $|G|$
3. is equal to $[G:N_G(P)]$ for any Sylow 3-subgroup $P$

Points (1) and (2) show that the number of Sylow 3-subgroups is either $1$ or $7$.

If there's only one, it's normal (and we can talk about *the* Sylow 3-subgroup $P$).  Then if $Q$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup, $PQ$ is a subgroup (because $P$ is normal), and it has order $6$.

If there are seven Sylow 3-subgroups, then point (3) shows $|N_G(P)|=6$, and we're already done.