# $G$ is a group of order $60$. Will $G$ always contain a subgroup of order $6$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a group of order $60$. Will there be a subgroup of order $ 6$?

Alternating group $A_5$ has a subgroup of order $6$. That is the group generated by this set $\{(123), (23) (45)\}$.

Will we be able to prove that there always exists a subgroup of order $6$   in a group of order $ 60$?

Can anyone help me to understand by giving a hint?

Comment: Maybe some similar questions will inspire you: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94548/ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2594060 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2911121

Comment: Okk I am trying to get some idea from them@TrevorGunn

Comment: Use Sylow theorems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems
Factor 60 and look at the Sylow subgroups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that's not always true. Take for example $G = C_5 \times A_4$. This group has order $60$ and no subgroups of order $6$. If you know that $A_4$ has no subgroups of order $6$ (it is the smallest group which fails to satisfy the converse of Lagrange's theorem), it is easy to find this example.

However, can you prove that this is the only exception?

Comment: $C_5$ means?@the_fox

Comment: Cyclic group of order $5$.

Comment: No I can not see why it is the only exception @the_fox

Comment: Do you know the fact that if $G$ has order $60$ and is not simple then it must have a normal subgroup of order $5$?